# Is there any classical analogy for quantum entanglement?

Tags: entanglement

I want to know if there is any classical analogy for understanding quantum entanglement.

Comment: This is a bit vague. What properties of quantum entanglement must be present in this classical 'object' (Algorithm? Hardware? Property of one of the previous? Something else?), for it to be the analogy you want?

Comment: @DiscreteLizard: I think, since quantum entanglement is a general property with a mathematical description, a similarly abstract answer about classical information would do.

Comment: I think it will be easy to argue endlessly about the answer: In some sense (locality, realism) there is no analogue in classical physics whilst in another sense (correlated probabilities), there is.

Comment: Is there any reason why this question should be here, rather than in [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)? I don't see any computing here.

Comment: I recommend going through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuvK-od647c) video by Veritasium and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54975/quantum-entanglement-whats-the-big-deal/54977#54977) excellent answer by @joshphysics on Physics SE. However, as such your question is off-topic here, as it is purely a physics question.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I think I was mainly confused as I already assumed the entanglement also needed to involve classical _computation_ of some sort. But it seems that involving computation was not the intention.